# SSH tunnel to Database from two level of jump server with different keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I have database server on AWS and from my PC i have to access that database using ssh tunneling for below scenario.

> PC --> Jump1 [x.pem, port:22] --> Jump2 [y.pem, port:443] --> mysqldb:3306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of scenarios, Config File is the best way to do it.

Run

```
$ touch ~/.ssh/config
```

Add host entries in a config file.

```
Host <Host_Name>
    HostName <URL/IP of Jump2>
    User <>
    Port <>
    Identityfile <yyy.pem>
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    ProxyCommand ssh -i <xxx.pem> <user>@<IP/DNS of Jump1> nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

and then to create a tunnel

```
$ ssh <local_port>:DB_URL:<DB PORT> <Host_name>
```

that's it. 
Now you can connect to DB using

```
localhost:<local_port>
```

Comment: I believe that -L was omitted before <local_port>:DB_URL:<DB PORT>

Answer (score 1):

If you already have your public keys in authorized_keys on respective hosts
then you can use `-J` directive.

like this:

```
ssh -J user1@host1 user2@host2
```

If you have more than one jump host you can concatenate it inside of `-J` directive like this:

```
ssh -J user1@host1,user2@host2,user(n-1)@host(n-1) userN@hostN
```

I also using port forwarding so it takes your port data all the way to the last site and then connect to specific site like this:

```
ssh -L 8080:microsoft.com:80 -J user1@host1 user2@host2
```

It will create unencrypted connection only from host2 to microsoft.com:80